# Как повернуть img, чтобы границы img остались в пределах div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

На странице есть следующий html:

```
<div style="border: 1px dotted red; float:left; padding:10px;">
   <img id="img" style="border:1px solid silver" />
</div>
```

Если с помощью jquery: `$('#img').css('transform','rotate(90deg)');` повернуть `img` на 90 градусов, то его граница выходит за пределы `div`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как повернуть тег `img`, чтобы его граница оставалась внутри `div`? При этом высота `div` может меняться, а ширина должна остаться без изменений.
<s>И как из кода на JavaScript создать/изменить изображение в теге `img` без загрузки файла?</s>

Comment: как вариант, если высота родителя непостоянна, то считывай эту высоту перед поворотом картинки, например, и присваивай её этой картинке. тогда она будет масштабироваться под родителя

Comment: `document.getElementById('img').src = '...'`; изменить картинку, `document.getElementById('img').style.height = '...'`; изменить её высоту

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _создать изображение в img?_

Comment: @Grundy _"что имеется ввиду под создать изображение в img?"_ -- как в c# что-то вроде: `using(var g = Graphics.From(img)) g.FillRectangle(...);`

Comment: @Stack, для этого может использоваться элемент canvas, а затем результат сохранен в img

Comment: Аууууууууууууу?

Comment: @Qwertiy _"Аууууууууууууу?"_ -- пока не могу ответить. занят [тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2286).

Comment: Вроде освободился?

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Убираем лишнее пространство, если высота больше ширины */
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -10000px; /* Значение заведомо больше высоты */
}
```

```html
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350×150&w=350&h=150"></span></div>
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150×350&w=150&h=350"></span></div>
```

Comment: на 90 работает. а возможно ли универсальное решение, чтобы можно было указать угол поворота из javascript?

Comment: @Stack, без известных пропорций - сомнительно. Но ты же просил на 90.

Comment: _"Но ты же просил на 90."_ -- если для 90 работает, то я думал, что если для любого другого угла поворота смогу сделать. оказалось, что с css не все так просто. но 90 тоже хорошо, спасибо, есть от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: @Stack, это тогда надо было какой-то произвольный угол просить. Для 90 почте везде будет особый способ. Кстати, а ведь скрипт может узнать размеры картинки и на их основе сделать css - почему бы таким вариантом не воспользоваться?

Comment: _"скрипт может узнать размеры картинки и на их основе сделать css"_ -- надо вычислять размер прямоугольника после поворота. и менять размер img. как раз смотрю как это можно сделать.

Comment: @Stack, нет не img. Размер вычислить просто, но там другая проблема. Ты мой удалённый ответ смотреть можешь? Хм.. Наверное нет, пока восстановил.

Comment: _"удалённый ответ смотреть можешь?"_ -- нет

Comment: @Stack, он уже не удалённый: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480803/178988

Comment: вижу. скопировал.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.red-border{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:50px auto;
  position:relative;
  transition:1s;
  background:red;
}
.orange-border{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid orange;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin-top:-100px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  border-radius:200px;
  line-height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  transition:.8s;
  background:orange;
}
.red-border:hover{
  transform:rotate(-180deg);
}
.red-border:hover .orange-border{
  transform:rotateY(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="red-border">
  <div class="orange-border">
      Hover Effect
  </div>
</div>
```

исправил ответ - так ?

Comment: _"вот так ?"_ -- это не то. нужен поворот по часовой стрелке на 90 градусов. и чтобы рис. оставался в границах своего контейнера.

Comment: _"исправил ответ"_ -- если красный тут вместо рисунка, то у него при повороте заметно как его угол выходит за пределы контейнера. а надо чтобы красный квадрат полностью был виден при повороте. для этого, его надо наверное уменьшать немного, чтобы он вписывался в контейнер.

Comment: гадать бесполезно , что вам нужно , в общем - тот самый красный это изображение ? а тот круглый это должен быть квадрат ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ukj2L14n/1/   вот так с фото

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ukj2L14n/2/  второй вариант - фото не выходит за рамки

Comment: если совсем это так надо что бы фото не  выходило то для родителя ставится overfow с параметром hidden , и всё

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со скриптом для произвольного угла поворота:

```js
function rotateImg(img, angle) {
  var width = img.clientWidth, height = img.clientHeight;
  var sina = Math.sin(angle), cosa = Math.cos(angle);

  img.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "rad)";
  img.style.left = height*sina + "px";
  
  var parentStyle = img.parentElement.style;
  parentStyle.width = width*cosa + height*sina + "px";
  parentStyle.height = width*sina + height*cosa + "px";
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  overflow: hidden; /* Избавляемся от лишнего пространства */
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350×150&w=350&h=150" onload="rotateImg(this,Math.PI/3)"></span></div>
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150×350&w=150&h=350" onload="rotateImg(this,Math.PI/3)"></span></div>
```

Comment: @Stack, исправил - теперь всё ровно.

Comment: Как оказалось, работает не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы картинка оставалась в границах и не выступала делай диву

```
overflow: hidden;
```

А на JavaScript создать картинку так

```
var newImg = document.createElement('img');//Создали пустой тег <img>
newImg.src = 'http://fafa.ru/image.png';// Установили аттрибут src
newImg.width = 100;
newImg.height = 100;
```

Comment: Изменить точно так же аттрибут.
Выбрать твою картинку по айди или классу, и изменить аттрибут src

var img = document.getElementById('kart1nka');
img.src = 'новая_ссылка';

Comment: при 'overflow: hidden' картинка выходит за пределы и ее часть просто не видна. а надо чтобы оставалась в пределах div и была видна полностью. `newImg.src = 'http:...` - не подходит. надо без обращения к серверу.

Comment: Если у тебя ширина дива будет без изменений, нужно тогда размеры картинки уменьшать.

newImg.src = это такой же аттрибут который и стоит у тебя в картинке, впихни туда значение картинки которая лежит в папке