# Взаимодействие transform rotate и flexbox

Tags: html, css, css3, transform

Возникла необходимость динамически поворачивать изображения, сверстанные через flexbox, собственно тут выяснилось, что после поворота изображения, для внешнего мира оно все так же продолжает занимать тоже самое положение. Как поведать всем о повороте? Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/x4f1xxqa/1/.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.element {
  margin: 5px;
}
.img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
#img {
  position: relative;
}
#test {
  background-color: black;
}
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='img'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <img id='img' class='rotated' width=100px src='http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/032011/kotiki-foto.jpg'>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='img'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='img'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='element rotated'>
    <div class='img' id='test'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='img'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480285/178988 - там есть два моих ответа.

Comment: Там решение конечно хорошее, но все же не полное. Оно работает только для угла от 0 до 90. Я еще поиграюсь, сегодня скорее всего доделаю для любого угла.
https://jsfiddle.net/x4f1xxqa/3/

Comment: Там есть полное решение для любых углов, но оно со скриптом, рассчитывающим новые размеры.

Comment: Да, я использовал именно эту функцию. Может я конечно что то делаю не так, но у меня она работает только до 90 градусов.
Можешь глянут тут ? https://jsfiddle.net/x4f1xxqa/5/

Comment: Да, что-то у меня не то с формулой... Скажу, если исправлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось, но думаю можно это все обобщить в одну общую формулу. Ну а пока главное что работает =)

```js
function rotateImg(img, angle){
  grade = angle;
  grade = grade % 360;
  if( grade <0 ){
    grade+=360;
  }
  angle = grade * Math.PI / 180;
  var width = img.clientWidth, height = img.clientHeight;
  img.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "rad)";
  switch( Math.floor( grade / 90 ) ){
    case 0:
      var sina = Math.sin(angle), cosa = Math.cos(angle);
      img.style.left = height*sina + "px";
      img.style.top = "0px";
      var parentStyle = img.parentElement.style;
      parentStyle.width = width*cosa + height*sina + "px";
      parentStyle.height = width*sina + height*cosa + "px";
      break;
    case 1:
      var sina = Math.sin((grade-90) * Math.PI / 180);
      var cosa = Math.cos((grade-90) * Math.PI / 180);
      img.style.left = (height*cosa+width*sina) + "px";
      img.style.top = height*sina + "px";
      var parentStyle = img.parentElement.style;
      parentStyle.height = width*cosa + height*sina + "px";
      parentStyle.width = width*sina + height*cosa + "px";
      break
      case 2:
      var sina = Math.sin((grade-180) * Math.PI / 180);
      var cosa = Math.cos((grade-180) * Math.PI / 180);
      img.style.left = width*cosa + "px";
      img.style.top = (width*sina + height*cosa) + "px";
      var parentStyle = img.parentElement.style;
      parentStyle.height = width*sina + height*cosa + "px";
      parentStyle.width = width*cosa + height*sina + "px";
      break
      case 3:
      var sina = Math.sin((grade-270) * Math.PI / 180);
      var cosa = Math.cos((grade-270) * Math.PI / 180);
      img.style.left = "0px";
      img.style.top = width*cosa + "px";
      var parentStyle = img.parentElement.style;
      parentStyle.height = width*cosa + height*sina + "px";
      parentStyle.width = width*sina + height*cosa + "px";
      break
  }
}

function rotateFun( img ){
  var img = img;
  var angle = 0;
  var start = Date.now(); // сохранить время начала
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // вычислить сколько времени прошло с начала анимации
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    if (angle == 360) {
      //clearInterval(timer);// конец через 2 секунды
      //return;
    }
    angle += 2;
    // рисует состояние анимации, соответствующее времени timePassed
    rotateImg( img, angle );

  }, 50);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  //overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200'>
  </span>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200' onload="rotateFun( this )">
  </span>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200'>
  </span>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200'>
  </span>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200'>
  </span>
  <span class='element'>
    <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=26&txt=50×100&w=100&h=200'>
  </span>
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/x4f1xxqa/8)