# Не получается повернуть текст в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица, в ее ячейке находится длинный текст, поворачиваю его на 90°, по сути ширина ячейки должна уменьшиться, но не уменьшается.

```css
.time-col{
  position:relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width:70px;
}
.col{
  background-color:#F0F;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <tr>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>1000-1500</div>
    </td>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>2000-3000</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2w6y7fm/2/

Пока смог придумать только грязный вариант решения:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2w6y7fm/3/

Comment: Вас не смущает, что во всей таблице только один <tr>, и тот незакрытый...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480545/178988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ширина не меняется, потому что трансформации не влияют на композитный слой, т. е. после применения какой-либо трансформации внешние габариты блока не пересчитываются. Вам придется сделать это вручную с помощью `.getBoundingClientRect()`.

Чтобы размеры трансформируемых блоков не оставляли за собой ширину, меньше которой ячейка не может быть, через JS необходимо задавать значение не свойству `width`, а свойству `max-width`. Самой ячейке также надо задать `vertical-align: bottom` и трансформируемому диву добавить `translateY(100%)` чтобы поворот на 90° осуществлялся правильно.

P.S. несмотря на то, что браузеры сами (почти всегда) правильно расставляют теги `thead`, `tbody`, `tr`, не забывайте делать это правильно вручную.

```js
let $timeCol = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.time-col'));

$timeCol.forEach(function(item, index) {
  let dimensions = item.getBoundingClientRect(),
      parent = item.closest('.col');
      
  parent.style.height = dimensions.height + 'px';
  parent.style.maxWidth = dimensions.width + 'px';
});
```

```css
.time-col{
  position:relative;
  transform: translateY(100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width:70px;
}

.col{
  background-color:#F0F;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>1000-1500</div>
    </td>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>2000-3000</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

как один из вариантов, пересчитать высоту jq:

```js
$('.rotate').each(function(){
  $(this)
    .css({
      'height': $(this).width(),
      'width' : '20px'
    });
});
```

```css
th, td {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rotate {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
  
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="rotate">Lorem ipsum.1</div></td>      
      <td><div class="rotate">Lorem ipsum dolor. .2</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный способ поворота текста — `writing-mode: vertical-lr` плюс, если необходимо, `transform: rotate(180deg)`.

```css
.time-col {
  position: relative;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.col{
  background-color: #F0F;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>1000-1500</div>
    </td>
    <td class='col'>
      <div class='time-col'>2000-3000</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```