# Обрезка изображения после поворота

Tags: алгоритм, изображения

Вначале было красное изображение, дабы его повернуть без потерь создается временное желтое, но оно избыточно.

[image: начало]
[image: начало]

Требуется обрезать временное желтое, до зеленого.

Подразумевается что исходное изображение может быть произвольного размера.
Угол поворота так же произволен.

Comment: пустые места становятся прозрачными (используется альфа канал)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480803/178988 - но там потом баг нашли, а я так и не исправил :(

Comment: частично решило проблему, но при последующих поворотах уже новой картинки, результат каждый раз увеличивается в размерах

Comment: ну обычно так и надо, но если нет, то написал другой ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нарисовать повернутый прямоугольник и его ограничивающий прямоугольник, и пометить углы, равные углу поворота Fi, то видно, например, что

```
CD = DH + HC = EH * Cos(Fi) + GH * Sin(Fi)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и формулы для размера будут такие:

```
New_Height = Old_Width * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Cos(Fi))
New_Width  = Old_Width * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы не указываете никаких деталей, то и ответ будет общим:

1. Вычисляете точку центра картинки `O`
2. Вычисляете точку угла картинки `C`
3. Поворачиваете картинку вокруг центра на некий известный вам угол `A`
4. Поворачиваете точку угла картинки на тот же угол

   ```
   x = O.x + (C.x - O.x) * Cos(A) + (C.y - O.y) * Sin(A);
   y = O.y - (C.x - O.x) * Sin(A) + (C.y - O.y) * Cos(A);
   ```
5. Вот вам и координаты `x` и `y` точки повернутого угла
6. Повторив 4 раза для всех углов, получаете мин-макс значения ограничивающего прямоугольника

P.S. Если у вас квадрат и точка вращения в центре, то достаточно координат 1 угла. 4 угла - это общее решение, удобное именно для прямоугольников не точно лежащих в центре.

Answer (score 2):

Если надо удалить все прозрачные края, то просто для каждого из них порверяем, сколько прозрачного мы можем срезать. Получатся 4 координаты, по которым надо вырезать прямоугольник (включительно).

```
var l, t, r, b;

for (l=0; l<width; ++l)
  for (var q=0; q<height; ++q)
    if (!isTransparent(l, q))
      break;

for (r=width-1; r>=l; --r)
  for (var q=0; q<height; ++q)
    if (!isTransparent(r, q))
      break;

for (t=0; t<height; ++t)
  for (var q=0; q<width; ++q)
    if (!isTransparent(q, t))
      break;

for (b=height-1; b>=t; --b)
  for (var q=0; q<width; ++q)
    if (!isTransparent(q, b))
      break;

crop(l, t, r, b);
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что при повторном повороте, прямоугольник будет немного расти, из-за повторяющейся интерполяции пикселей на краях/углах. Но это скорее проблема самого алгоритма ТС - картинку лучше каждый раз заново из исходного положения поворачивать.